# not able to run bash cgi script

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Content-type: text/html\n\n"

sudo convert /usr/lib/cgi-bin/images/* /usr/lib/cgi-bin/images.pdf

sudo ocrmypdf /usr/lib/cgi-bin/images.pdf /usr/lib/cgi-bin/pdf/images_ocr.pdf

printf "done"
```

- above script is in cgi-bin folder with 755 permission
- in browser http://localhost/cgi-bin/script.sh
- script runs and only prints but no sudo cmd is executed plz help

Answer (score 0):

These lines should be

```
sudo convert ~/usr/lib/cgi-bin/images/* ~/usr/lib/cgi-bin/images.pdf
sudo ocrmypdf ~/usr/lib/cgi-bin/images.pdf ~/usr/lib/cgi-bin/pdf/images_ocr.pdf
```

Without the `~` it's a relative path to the folder in which the script is executed.

Comment: when run using terminal it runs properly but when executed by  http://localhost/cgi-bin/script.sh browser convert and ocrmypdf cmd do not work

Answer (score 0):

If you already are in cgi-bin and won't change location :

```
sudo convert images/* images.pdf
sudo ocrmypdf images.pdf pdf/images_ocr.pdf
```

so you're not dependent on your root's folder structure and only on your project's

Comment: tried this but only "done" gets printed , convert and ocrmypdf cmd are not executed